# Flutter Firestore, ShowTimePicker Invalid argument: Instance of 'TimeOfDay' error

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using ShowTimePicker widget in my app with TimeOfDay data. Flutter gives me this error:

> Invalid argument: Instance of 'TimeOfDay'

I don't want to add this data as String type to Firestore. I want to add this "time" data as timestamp. How can I do this?

```
TimeOfDay time = TimeOfDay.now();
```

> this is my add data method to firestore:

```
void addData2() {
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final User user = auth.currentUser;
final uid = user.uid;

var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
map['ilac'] = ilacText.text;
map['miktar'] = miktarText.text;
map["tarih"] = _dateTime;
map["bitistarih"] = _dateTime2;
map["periyot"] = timesdata;
map["tur"] = turdata;
map["saat"] = time  ;



FirebaseFirestore.instance.
collection('users').
doc(uid).
set({

  "ilacvemiktar": FieldValue.arrayUnion([ map])
}, SetOptions(merge: true)

).catchError((e) {
  print(e);
});
}
```

> this is my ShowTimePicker Widget:

```
            Container(
            height: 40, width: 200,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black38,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18)
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14, 0, 14, 0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Text( time == null ? "İlaç Saati" :time.format(context), textAlign: 
              TextAlign.center
                ,
                style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                    color:  Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),),
              onTap: () async {
                final TimeOfDay selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialTime: TimeOfDay.now() ,


                  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
                    return MediaQuery(
                      data: MediaQuery.of(context)
                          .copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: false),
                      child: Theme(
                          data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
                            colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                              primary: Colors.cyan[700],
                              onPrimary: Colors.cyan[700],
                              surface: Colors.white,
                              onSurface: Colors.cyan[700],
                            ),
                            dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.cyan[700],
                          ),
                          child: child),
                    );
                  },
                );
                print(selectedTime);
                setState(() {
                  time = selectedTime ;
                });


              },
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [official firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue) you can use firestore server values made for this type of situation - `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` which is explained as the following:

> A placeholder value for auto-populating the current timestamp (time
> since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) as determined by the Firebase
> servers.
>
> Example
>
> ```
>  var sessionsRef = firebase.database().ref("sessions");
>  sessionsRef.push({   startedAt:
>  firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP });
> ```

Aditionally if you wish to the server's current time you could use the fieldValue `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`, more information on this other option [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue#serverTimestamp()). This could save you the trouble of having various time zones which may result in confusion if different time zones are mixed and saved.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing the instance of TimeOfDay in firebase, you should pass something like this time.hour or time.minutes